# drawrect Vs layoutsubviews - NSView - Cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsview, drawrect

I can't find a decent answer to explain me the difference between these 2 functions.
when does every one gets called, and how does one different then the other ?

for example , can't I just layout my views inside drawrect ?

Thanks

Comment: `NSView` comes from `AppKit` but `UIKit`, that's Cocoa not Cocoa Touch framework, right?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`-layoutSubviews` is called from `-layoutIfNeeded` if the "layout needed" flag was set (using `-setNeedsLayout`, or automatically when the view bounds changes). Use it for positioning <strike>your view</strike> [**EDIT:** Use it for positioning *subviews*].

`-drawRect:` is called from `-displayIfNeeded` if the "display needed" flag was set (using `-setNeedsDisplay`, or automatically if you set `view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw`).

Both `-layoutIfNeeded` and `-displayIfNeeded` are called automatically by UIKit/CoreAnimation before things are drawn to screen; you rarely need to call them directly.

You can position your subviews in `-drawRect:` (you can even add subviews!), but this is unwise:

- By default, `-setNeedsDisplay` is not called automatically on a bounds change.
- Implementing `-drawRect:` reduces performance (UIKit/CoreAnimation has to create a bitmap-backed graphics context for you); only do so if you need to perform custom drawing.
- You need to redraw the view in `-drawRect:`. Drawing is expensive. Moving views around is cheap.
- UIKit/CoreAnimation probably does a layout pass followed by a drawing pass. CoreAnimation can use layout information to decide what views need drawing (e.g. it could ignore views obscured by opaque subviews, off-screen views, or subviews outside the bounds of a clipsToBounds=YES view; or it could only draw a sub-rect of a large view). If you move views during the drawing pass, CoreAnimation might not draw them correctly.

**EDIT:** And some more detail when I'm awake:

What's the difference between "display" and "draw"? Displaying is done by`-[CALayer display]`; the default implementation is (approximately)

- If the layer's delegate responds to `-displayLayer:`, call  `[self.delegate displayLayer:self]`. `-displayLayer:` is supposed to set `layer.content` to (e.g.) a CGImage,
- Otherwise, if the layer's delegate responds to `-drawLayer:inContext:`, set up a bitmap-backed context, call `[self.delegate drawLayer:self inContext:context]`, and save the output to `layer.content` (the output is actually a CABackingStore, which is presumably a private API)
- Otherwise, don't change `layer.content`.

The view is the layer's delegate, so you can implement `-[MyView displayLayer:]` instead, and do interesting stuff like

- `self.layer.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"].CGImage)` (which is roughly what UIImageView does)
- A no-op, to prevent any "drawing". This might be useful if you've subclassed e.g. UIToolbar and want to give it a transparent background. (This also prevents creation of the CGContext/CABackingStore.)
- Move subviews around without the performance penalty (but it's still not a good idea for the reasons above).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I don't have all the answers, but I can say you that :
- layoutSubviews is called when the view frame is changed
- drawRect is called when setNeedDisplay is called

Most of the time you won't use layoutSubviews.

There may be others cases, but it could give you a first piece of answer ^^

Good luck

Comment: Please give more detail around your assertion that "most of the time you won't use layoutSubviews."